# How to become 'self-employed'?

Tags: self-employment

What kinds of 'work' could a person do to be self-employed? To me honestly, it seems like doing such would overlap with entrepreneurship. I have considered becoming such myself, but seriously setting up a business and would quite difficult seeing as I've never had an actual job before.

Honestly, any kind of income where I don't technically have a boss would be nice, even if it doesn't technically constitute 'employment'. I know there's lots of people who make money on youtube, but that's only become increasingly difficult to do over the years for various reasons, and right now many such people are seriously worried about their future.

Comment: _"people make money on youtube, but that's only become increasingly difficult to do over the years for various reasons"_ No. The exact opposite is true. Realistically however you should find a regular job first to get some real world experience. Maybe you'll come up with a business idea along the way.

Answer (score 4):

> What kinds of 'work' could a person do to be
>   self-employed?

You can do any kind of work that someone would give you money to do.

Some people play music on the sidewalk. Some people consult to Fortune 500 companies. There are an endless number of possibilities.

Think about your skills. Think about how you could convince someone to pay you for using those skills to their advantage. Think about what it would be worth to someone else to pay you.

Comment: I heard that performing in the streets like that is only legal in New York, and even then you have to get permission to do it.